# How can I remove border of all child elements of a parent div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing a problem that I want to remove all child elements border of a container div using jQuery.

Child elements can be image, div, p tag, or anchor or any HTML tag.

Here's my try:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#div1").children("div").css("border","0px solid red");
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FjcF5/26/)

Comment: All children or all descendants?

Comment: Always include relevant code/markup *in the question itself*. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: only on children or also on childrens children?
so what about the line `<div style="border:solid 1px red"> mayank mathur </div>`?

Comment: thanks to all Flip answer solve my problem .and @T.J.Crowder in future i always post the code here.thanks again

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Just doing it in the future would leave this question in exactly the situation described in the meta link. Things like this are why questions and answered *can be edited*. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change children to find, like this.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#div1").find("*").css("border", "0");
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yu25h/

Answer (score 0):

[The all selector?](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

```
$("#div1").find("*").css("border","0");
```

Comment: Eh? Seriously? I've used it, and it has passed rigorous x-browser QA and testing and made it to production.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That's talking about *retrieving* with `.css()`, not setting. Or at least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: If you read the sentence after what @T.J.Crowder posted it says "For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin", it's specifically talking about retrieving.

Comment: @thirtydot, Filip, and karim79: I hope it is, and have [asked the question](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/are-shorthand-properties-supported-in-css-propertyname-value). Also removed comments here, relative to the actual question being answered this is a side-track anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's easy:

```
$("#div1 *").css({
    border: "none"
});
```

Or if you have a jquery-object of your parent:

```
var $div = $("#div1");
$div.find("*").css({
    border: "none"
});
```

If you know that you just want to remove borders from div-elements instead of all elements inside, just use:

```
var $div = $("#div1");
$div.find("div").css({
    border: "none"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for all children it will be
`$("#div1").children().css("border", "0");`

But if you add the borders by the style attribute like you did before you could also go for

`$("#div1").children().removeAttr("style");`

Hope this helps